# Does anyone know how to plot a dome (aka half sphere) in MATLAB...or anyother programming language?

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to plot a dome or half a sphere and be able to change the dimensions of the dome.  I figured MATLAB would be my best choice.

any suggestions?

THanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SPHERE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sphere.html) function generates x, y, and z coordinates for a spherical surface. You just have to remove points corresponding to the bottom of the sphere to make a dome. For example:

```
[x,y,z] = sphere;      %# Makes a 21-by-21 point sphere
x = x(11:end,:);       %# Keep top 11 x points
y = y(11:end,:);       %# Keep top 11 y points
z = z(11:end,:);       %# Keep top 11 z points
r = 3;                 %# A radius value
surf(r.*x,r.*y,r.*z);  %# Plot the surface
axis equal;            %# Make the scaling on the x, y, and z axes equal
```

Comment: @dewalla: I updated my answer to show how you can index into x, y, and z to get the points you want.

Comment: Is there a way to make it a dome rather than a sphere? (aka the x y and z components are not all the same?

Comment: @dewalla: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "dome". The code above cuts the sphere in half and plots this hemisphere. If you're wanting to deform the hemisphere to flatten or stretch it in certain directions, then you can scale each variable (`x`, `y`, and `z`) by a different amount instead of the same amount `r`.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at `surf`. the formula for a sphere is

```
x^2+y^2+z^2 = R^2
```

you may also need `meshgrid`

Comment: The help for `surf` even has an example of drawing a sphere.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starting point:

```
R = 7;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:.1:10);
Z = sqrt(R.^2 - X.^2 - Y.^2);
Z(imag(Z) ~= 0) = 0;
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a circle graph I made and adapted it to graph a dome. I can't test it but it should work since the circle worked fine.

I made this in JavaScript.
`setVox` is just a function that will print a voxel on a 3D plane.

```
  var rad = 1; //radius

  for (var z = -(rad); z < 0; z++) {
    r = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rad,2) - Math.pow(z,2)));
    for (var x = -(r); x < r; x++) {
      y = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r,2) - Math.pow(x,2)));
      setVox(x,y,z);
      setVox(x,-(y),z);
    }
    for (y = -(r); y < r; y++) {
      x = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r,2) - Math.pow(y,2)));
      setVox(x,y,z);
      setVox(-(x),y,z);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could download and use this [`hemisphere`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/125090-hemisphere) function, which is just an adapted version of the default MATLAB `sphere` function. For example:

```
[X,Y,Z] = hemisphere;
R = 2;
X1 = R*X + 3;
Y1 = R*Y - 4;
Z1 = R*Z + 2;
surf(X1,Y1,Z1)
axis equal
```

Resulting plot:
[image: Hemisphere plot from above code]

Comment: If you could please add the image as an inline image, instead of a link, that will be much more helpful, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, since I don't have at least 10 reputation points at this moment, this option is disabled for me. Feel free to edit my comment if you can. thanks